# User friendly way of closing node.js websocket connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket, server

I have an application that spins up websocket connections on random ports after checking to make sure the port has not yet been assigned. Each connection has a front facing card with a slider to create/destroy the TCP connection based on the port number they are assigned (and stored). It is simple to spin up a server for each socket with the predefined event handling that it comes with but i am unsure of a way to allow the user to kill the tcp connection. What this would look like is the user from the front end woudl slide the toggle intot eh off position and I would take that entities id, query for its port number and would then need to close that port's connection. I am hoping there is a way with node to be able to query for its active servers and act on them as one pleases but I have not found any articles suggesting a way.

Comment: Why would you spin up multiple servers for this?  You can just have multiple clients connect to the SAME server.  That is the usual and common design.

Comment: FYI, there is no "node.js way" to query for servers that it has started.  You can just keep track of them in an array as you start them.  But, I still maintain that it's likely you don't need multiple webSocket servers, that one will probably do just fine for all your clients and thus the problem you're asking about goes away.

Comment: @jfriend00 for security reasoning. each port has its own corresponding settings and is teh sole ownership of the organization that is using it.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you need multiple webSocket servers.  Security can be implemented just fine on a connection, one doesn't need a separate webSocket server for that.

Comment: Ill have to think this over. You probably have a point

Answer (score 0):

> I am hoping there is a way with node to be able to query for its active servers and act on them as one pleases but I have not found any articles suggesting a way.

There is no such thing built into node.js.

If you wanted to be able to operate on all the webSocket servers you had started, then you could just add them to an array as you start them.

```
const serverArray = [];


// code elsewhere that starts a server
let server = new WebSocketServer(someRandomPort);
// push an object into an array that has the port and server
serverArray.push({server, port: someRandomPort});
```

Then, you could iterate over that array at any time to do something to all of them or to find a server that is using a particular port.

---

But, it sounds to me like you don't really need multiple webSocket servers.  Multiple clients (with however much security you want) can all share the same server.  That's the usual client/server design (multiple clients talking to one server).

Comment: @colinrickels - Does this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.  If not, then please indicate what is not yet answered.